# Calculating inner resistance of a linear dipole

Tags: resistance, dipole

I've been stuck on a question for a while now, so I'd really appreciate if you could take a look at this: I'm supposed to calculate the dipole's inner resistance. I've got that E= 15V, R1= 1200 Ohm and R2= 3700 Ohm. The size of Rb is a variable from 0 to 10 MOhm.

This is what the figure looks like:

[image]

Comment: What does this have to do with a “dipole”?

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the voltage source into a current source, then you have the resistors R1 and R2 in parallel, then \$Ri = \frac{R1*R2}{(R1+R2)}\$.

Edit:

If I understand you correctly then Rb is the load resistance.

1. Take that off.
2. Transform voltage source into current source

   For this you grab the voltage source and a resistor in series, here R1 and calculate \$I_0 = E/R1\$ and then you can display it like this.

   [image]
3. Then you can summarize the resistances. \$Ri = R1 || R2\$

   [image]
4. Convert back to power source
5. Connect Rb

   [image]
6. Now insert voltage divider

   \$E/Eb = \frac{(Ri+Rb)}{Rb} \Rightarrow Eb= \frac{E* Rb }{ (Ri+Rb)}\$

Comment: and how would i convert the voltage source?